# Django 1.9.2 AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have setup 3 servers now with PostgreSQL and have so far not seen this issue. I am now setting up the first server which is not running on a danish server, and i start getting errors when accessing the database from the web.

I could use createsuperuser without issues and it created my super user. But when i try to use it to login to my site i get the error.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",    line 1239, in cursor_iter
sentinel):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1238, in <lambda>
for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(GET_ITERATOR_CHUNK_SIZE)),
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 102, in  inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/utils.py", line 6, in utc_tzinfo_factory
raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC
```

I have been looking at the code and the error comes from this code.

```
from django.utils.timezone import utc
def utc_tzinfo_factory(offset):
    if offset != 0:
    raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
return utc
```

Though i cannot find where offset is initiated, so i cannot figure out how Django decides that my offset is off.

My postgresql database have timezone set to UTC and have verified all postgresql parameters written in the django documentation and i am now running out of ideas of why this happens.

I hope someone here can help?

python3.4 -V: Python 3.4.3

psql -V: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.15

django-admin --version: 1.9.2

**UPDATED 11/8-2016 - Full Stack from DEBUG view**

I found the value for the offset in the utc_tzinfo_factory, it has the value of 120. Though i cannot explain how or why it gets this value.

Below is a copy from the debug page of Django for the error with full stack and variables.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://myweb.dk/accounts/login/

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'teamTournamentApp.apps.TeamtournamentappConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in inner
  49.         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  69.         if form.is_valid():

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  363.         self._clean_form()

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  390.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py" in clean
  159.                                            password=password)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  74.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  17.             user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in get_by_natural_key
  45.         return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  381.         num = len(clone)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  240.         self._fetch_all()

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  68.         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  805.         for rows in results:

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in cursor_iter
  1239.                          sentinel):

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <lambda>
  1238.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(GET_ITERATOR_CHUNK_SIZE)),

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  102.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/utils.py" in utc_tzinfo_factory
  6.         raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")

Exception Type: AssertionError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: database connection isn't set to UTC

Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
next    
''
password    
'xxxxxxx'
username    
'admin'
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'f8E50d9kpS2j4Wlc7O9KsKtUXHxbuX58'
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
_ga 
'GA1.2.1308578855.1465289038'
csrftoken   
'f8E50d9kpS2j4Wlc7O9KsKtUXHxbuX58'
META
Variable    Value
UNIQUE_ID   
'xxxxx'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36')
mod_wsgi.total_requests 
1
REMOTE_ADDR 
'xx.yy.zz.tt'
mod_wsgi.handler_script 
''
mod_wsgi.script_name    
''
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
REQUEST_SCHEME  
'http'
mod_wsgi.script_start   
'1470934394985429'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://myweb.dk/accounts/login/'
mod_wsgi.version    
(4, 5, 3)
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
HTTP_HOST   
'myweb.dk'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate'
PATH_INFO   
'/accounts/login/'
wsgi.multiprocess   
True
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
mod_wsgi.listener_port  
'80'
mod_wsgi.path_info  
'/accounts/login/'
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs'
REMOTE_PORT 
'59723'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='utf-8'>
mod_wsgi.callable_object    
'application'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
REQUEST_URI 
'/accounts/login/'
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
'/var/www/vhosts/myweb.dk/httpdocs/TeamTournament/TeamTournament/wsgi.py'
SERVER_ADMIN    
'.....'
mod_wsgi.request_start  
'1470934394985053'
mod_wsgi.listener_host  
''
mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile    
'0'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
mod_wsgi.script_reloading   
'1'
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
''
mod_wsgi.application_group  
'myweb.dk|'
mod_wsgi.thread_requests    
0
wsgi.input  
<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f6266286920>
QUERY_STRING    
''
SERVER_ADDR 
'xx.yy.zz.tt'
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
CONTEXT_PREFIX  
''
wsgi.run_once   
False
REQUEST_METHOD  
'POST'
HTTP_ORIGIN 
'http://myweb.dk'
SERVER_NAME 
'myweb.dk'
mod_wsgi.request_handler    
'wsgi-script'
mod_wsgi.process_group  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'Apache'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'_ga=GA1.2.1308578855.1465289038; csrftoken=f8E50d9kpS2j4Wlc7O9KsKtUXHxbuX58'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,sv;q=0.2'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
apache.version  
(2, 4, 6)
PATH_TRANSLATED 
'/var/www/vhosts/myweb.dk/httpdocs/TeamTournament/TeamTournament/wsgi.py/accounts/login/'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
'91'
mod_wsgi.thread_id  
2
CSRF_COOKIE 
'f8E50d9kpS2j4Wlc7O9KsKtUXHxbuX58'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs'
Settings
Using settings module TeamTournament.settings
Setting Value
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
[]
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
[]
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['xx.yy.zz.tt', 'myweb.net', 'myweb.dk']
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
EMAIL_PORT  
25
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
USE_ETAGS   
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmal'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['/var/www/vhosts/myweb.dk/httpdocs/TeamTournament/templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request']}}]
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
['django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
 'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
 'django.template.context_processors.media',
 'django.template.context_processors.static',
 'django.template.context_processors.tz',
 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']
DEBUG_APPS  
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
ADMINS  
[]
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
PRODUCTION  
False
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MANAGERS    
[]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
APPEND_SLASH    
True
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
['django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader']
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'TeamTournament.settings'
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
BASE_DIR    
'/var/www/vhosts/myweb.dk/httpdocs/TeamTournament'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
DEBUG   
True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
USE_L10N    
True
STATICFILES_DIRS    
[]
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
STATIC_ROOT 
'/var/www/vhosts/myweb.dk/httpdocs/static/'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
TIME_ZONE   
'CET'
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
             'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
             'NAME': 'user',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '5432',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': 'user'}}
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
USE_I18N    
True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'TeamTournament.urls'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'TeamTournament.wsgi.application'
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
POSTGRES    
True
PREPEND_WWW 
False
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
LOGGING 
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'filters': {'require_debug_false': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'}},
 'handlers': {'logfile': {'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
                          'filename': '/var/log/django/error.log'},
              'mail_admins': {'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                              'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                              'level': 'ERROR'}},
 'loggers': {'django': {'handlers': ['logfile'],
                        'level': 'ERROR',
                        'propagate': False},
             'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                                'level': 'ERROR',
                                'propagate': True}},
 'version': 1}
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
INSTALLED_APPS  
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'teamTournamentApp.apps.TeamtournamentappConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
MEDIA_URL   
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
LOG_PATH    
'/var/log/django/error.log'
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
USE_TZ  
True
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```

Comment: What is the value of TIME_ZONE and USE_TZ in your settings.py?

Comment: TIME_ZONE is CET and USE_TZ is True. I noticed my other servers have Europe/Copenhagen timezone in postgresql. And tried to change postgresql to this timezone. Same error. Also tried to change the TIME_ZONE to be UTC in settings and postgresql timezone is UTC. Still the same error.

Comment: I have same issue. The pg_timezone_names shows correct info (UTC in both name and abbrev). If anyone else has solved this, help!

Comment: Did you check the solution below? It solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for responding Lars. Yes, I checked pg_timezone_names both from psql and from with django shell. I only have this issue running django tests, not in the django dev or prod systems I am running, so I am looking further into why this only happens when running django tests

Comment: If you create the dates in your test code. Then check what timezone you are using. It could be where the problem comes, because you have not activated the expected timezone in your test data, because it uses the local machine timezone, where when you use your browser it is using your computers timezone.

Comment: @LarsOlafsson, exactly right. thank you sir. I added conn.execute("SET  TIME ZONE 'UTC'") before my tests and it worked

Comment: @MIkee, had the same issue when I transferred the server on a Windows machine. The problem was the psycopg2 package. After setting psycopg2>=2.8,<2.9 in the requirements.txt, it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks vinkomlacic. I wound up re writing the code to use native Django ORM and ditched the raw sql in psycopg2. Strange because I use raw sql in many other places with no problem...

Comment: The error went away for me on windows by installing both: psycopg2==2.8.6 and psycopg2-binary==2.8.6 and uninstalling the latest version of any of both that were installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered this same problem, also with a server that is normally running with the UTC+2 (in my case, Europe/Oslo).

It turned out that the system zoneinfo files on my server (Centos 7) were corrupted, which became evident in `pg_timezone_names`.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_timezone_names where name like 'UTC';
 name | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
------+--------+------------+--------
 UTC  | CEST   | 02:00:00   | t
(1 row)
```

After running `yum update tzdata` to update my server's timezone files,  and restarting the PostgreSQL server, the issue appears to be resolved.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_timezone_names where name like 'UTC';
 name | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
------+--------+------------+--------
 UTC  | UTC    | 00:00:00   | f
(1 row)
```

My guess it that I might previously have run `cat /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Oslo > /etc/localtime` without first removing `/etc/localtime` to change the timezone on the system, effectively overwriting the zoneinfo for UTC with the zoneinfo for Europe/Oslo.

Comment: You are a hero! For me i had the mots up to date tzdata, but did a reinstall of the tzdata with "yum reinstall tzdata", and restarted postgres. And now the Django exception was gone! Good timing, was just about to reinstall the whole server, you just saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

For 18/06/2021 this is a known issue, which comes from the [psycopg-2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)/[psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) packages. Fortunately, they already have an [open issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1293) on their GitHub page, so hopefully it gets fixed soon.

As a temporary fix, you can pin the version in your `requirements.txt` to `psycopg2-binary>=2.8,<2.9` or `psycopg2>=2.8,<2.9`, depending on what package you are using.

Thanks to @[vinkomlacic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8810865/vinkomlacic) for mentioning this in comments.

Comment: 2021 solution AHOI

Comment: saving you the click on the now closed issue: "tl; dr: if you are using Django 2.2 you must use psycopg < 2.9 in your requirements file."

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple workaround that I found to fix the issue for me.
That is to set:

```
USE_TZ = False
```

This helps to solve the issue.
By default it is set to True, so that gives the error for me when I use PostgreSql on Heroku. Maybe some synchronization happens between Django engine and the database.

Comment: This worked for me, bumping around psycopg2 versions isn't helping (using Django 2.1.3)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using psycopg2 2.9, downgrade to psycopg2==2.8.6 or pip3 install psycopg2-binary==2.8.6.
This issue is caused by a recent update to psycopg2, version 2.9.

Comment: It worked for me on windows by installing both: psycopg2==2.8.6 and psycopg2-binary==2.8.6

Comment: Seems like this issue is mostly related to **Django 2.2**, and here is the [link](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1293) to the GitHub ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for the answer KFH, it helped me a lot. In case you are using Ubuntu, the following should fix it:

```
sudo apt install tzdata --reinstall
```

The problem was the same for me, as I had previously run `sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Montreal /etc/localtime` which messed with my postgres db. Re-installing `tzdata` and restarting postgres fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error got solved for me on **windows** by installing both: psycopg2==2.8.6 and psycopg2-binary==2.8.6 and uninstalling the latest version of any of both that were installed.