# database connection isn't set to UTC - Django getting timestamp

Tags: python, django, postgresql, timezone

**Set-up**

I'm trying to run unit tests in Django.

`pipenv run python manage.py test test_module.tests.test_application.ExampleTest`

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\Documents\Development\Projects\project_test\data_load_api_functions\tests\test_deepcrawl_api.py", line 210, in setUp
    print(list(User.objects.all()))
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1130, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1509, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1509, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dom_W\.virtualenvs\example-project-n37Jnk2\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\utils.py", line 9, in utc_tzinfo_factory
    raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC
```

I think it might've started because of the switch to BST, but now despite forcing timezone I can't get Django to recognise it.

**What I've tried**

I set the default Postgres timezone to UTC in `postgresql.conf`

That did nothing so I inspected the function which is responsible:

```
def utc_tzinfo_factory(offset):
    if offset != 0:
        raise AssertionError("database connection isn't set to UTC")
    return utc
```

And discovered it's being given a `datetime.timedelta` with a value of `0:00:00` which then causes this line to fail:

`if offset != 0:`

Why isn't it receiving an integer? And how on earth can I fix this?

If I comment out the line, then it all just works fine... But otherwise there is some sort of timezone mismatch.

**Env**

- Windows 10
- Django: 2.2
- Postgresql: 13

Comment: It appears to be something to do with: https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/

Comment: Recent issue related to a new version of `psycopg2`. Check this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68024060/assertionerror-database-connection-isnt-set-to-utc

Comment: Thank you @AnasTiour, that is exactly it!