# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'rsplit' error on Django 2.x 3.x 4.x with postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql

This error may point to a model but it is mainly an incompatibility with Postgres package.

In a new postgres databases it may include following error when doing initial migration: "AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC"

I got same error with Python 3.8 & 3.10 + Django 3 & 4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [AssertionError: database connection isn't set to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68024060/assertionerror-database-connection-isnt-set-to-utc) the issue is the psycopg2 version 2.9 which is incompatible with Django 2.x, 3.x & 4.x.

The solution is very simple:

You can downgrade to 2.8.6 using:

pip install psycopg2==2.8.6

or

pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.6

Then it all works as usual.